# Creating variable based on if values of two data frames are equal

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c('hds23','has21','her10','hds21','hss23','has23'))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c('hds23','her10','hds21'))
```

What I would like to do is have all the IDs on `df2` that are in `df1` be labeled in a new variable in `df1$Status` as 'TA' and all others as "NoTA"

I've tried `ifelse()` but it gives the following errors:

```
Warning message:
In LACoursesTable1$YearCourseSec == CourseTable$YearCourseSec :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

This is what I would like `df1` to look like

```
ID       Status
hds23    TA
has21    NTA
her10    TA
hds21    TA
hss23    NTA
has23    NTA
```

Comment: `df1$Status <- ifelse(df1$ID %in% df2$ID, "TA", "NoTA")` seems to produce your desired result?

Comment: @Nate I get this message "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, TA, value = c("NTA", "TA", "NTA",  : 
  replacement has 197 rows, data has 666"

Comment: Never mind it worked! I had the data frames in the wrong order. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways using some *tidy* functionality:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c('hds23','has21','her10','hds21','hss23','has23')
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c('hds23','her10','hds21')
)


df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    Status = if_else(
      ID %in% df2$ID,
      'TA',
      'noTA'
    )
  )

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  semi_join(df2, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(Status = 'TA') %>% 
  bind_rows(
    df1 %>% 
      anti_join(df2, by = 'ID') %>% 
      mutate(Status = 'noTA')
  )

> df1
     ID Status
1 hds23     TA
2 her10     TA
3 hds21     TA
4 has21   noTA
5 hss23   noTA
6 has23   noTA
>
```

The first approach uses a conditional `if_else(<cond>, <true>, <false>)` while the second uses two separate joins (`semi_join` for matching items and `anti_join` for missing items), bound together in the rows.